# How to create an ArrayList of Text Files in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I'm trying to create an ArrayList of pre-existing text files (basically take a folder of text files that are already saved on my computer and plug them into an ArrayList) so that I can iterate over them and send matching pairs of text files to another program (a separate java program) for data analysis. Is it possible to create an ArrayList of text files the way I want to?

Comment: Yes, what exactly did you try? Please read [ask]. You can simply create a `File` object and insert many of them to an `ArrayList` of type `File`.

Comment: fleshold, the answer to the question you asked is 'Yes, it is possible". That probably seems pedantic to you, but it's important to understand that StackOverflow exists to answer _specific_ technical problems. Your question seems to be looking for someone to write code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ever since the java.nio package was introduced, this has become simple enough, especially with Java 8 streams:

```
Files.walk(new File("/your/base/dir").toPath()) // stream of all files inside base folder
     .filter(p->p.getFileName().endsWith(".txt")) // limit to .txt files
     .map(Path::toAbsolutePath) // convert to absolute pathy
     .forEach(System.out::println); // print
```

See: [`Files.walk(path, option...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)

Comment: Using a DirectorStream could be a viable alternative. A bit easier on the eyes too, especially when you need to filter based on a complex filter.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex meh, it has an imperative interface and a "magic" factory method, no me gusta. But feel free to add it as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

In apache commons-io, there is a class called FileUtils which will return a List of Files.

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class TestFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File dir = new File("<dir>");
        String[] extensions = new String[] { "txt" };
        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);

    }

}
```